# Kafka Topic Jammed up despite having more than 30 kafka-monitor replicas

Tags: python, apache-kafka, scrapy

`demo.incoming` topic in Kafka keeps piling up.

I am using [scrapy cluster](https://scrapy-cluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/introduction/overview.html). About 70 requests per second are submitted to Kafka via Scrapy Cluster REST api (Producer). The spiders can finish the crawl pretty fast because the queue in redis remains at a very low number, less than 10 most of the time. But the number of messages in `demo.incoming` keep piling up every second. This is the command I used to check the number of messages in `demo.incoming` topic in Kafka

```sh
kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell \
--broker-list localhost:9092,kafka-statefulset-2:9092,kafka-statefulset-1:9092 \
--topic demo.incoming \
--time -1 --offsets 1 | awk -F ":" '{sum += $3} END {print sum}'
```

I thought it was because Kafka-monitor(Consumer) cannot pick up the message from Kafka and push to redis fast enough that causes `demo.incoming` topic to pile up. Despite of scaling up Kafka-monitor to 30 replicas, the topics still keeps piling up.

The number of partitions of this topic is 8 showing in the screenshot.

[image]

In theory, the number of messages in Kafka should remain at a very low number. Because the Consumer, Kafka-monitor in this case, should consume the message as soon as it arrives considering it has more than 30 replicas.

Comment: This question was resolved here. https://github.com/istresearch/scrapy-cluster/issues/221#event-2468747515

Answer (score 1):

That command lists the ending offsets of all partitions, not the "number of messages" within the topic (which there is no precise command for without calculations of start *and* end offsets). The sum you're making is always going to be increasing. The rate at which that value increases would only tell you how fast the producer is acting, not the consumption rate.

If you want to check out the number of messages yet to be processed by a consumer group, you'd use `kafka-consumer-groups` tool

Since the topic actually has 8 partitions, then there can only be at most 8 consumers in the same group at once for that topic, though I'm not sure how your Kafka monitor tool works

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. So basically **Kafka-monitor** take the message and push to **redis** database. I think you are right. The command I used to check number of messages is not correct. However, I yet to figure out how to use **kafka-consumer-groups**

Comment: The command I use to check the lag on a consumer group `kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group [consumer-group-name]`